Why are smooth irreducible representations of the Weil group finite dimensional?
I am trying to understand the proof in Bushnell and Henniart - The local Langlands conjecture for $\operatorname{GL}_2$ of the fact (§28.6, Lemma 1) that smooth irreducible representations of the Weil group are finite dimensional.
I have several doubts about the proof. The proof is:

Let $(\rho,V)$ be a smooth irreducible representation of the Weil group $W_F$ of a non Archimedean local field $F$. Let $v\in V$, $v \neq 0$. $V$ is irreducible, so the elements $\rho(x)v$ with $x \in W_F$ generate all $V$. Since $V$ is smooth, $v$ is fixed by an open subgroup of $W_F$ and so by an open subgroup of the inertia group $I_F$. These groups are of the form $J=I_F \cap \Omega_E$ where $\Omega_E$ is an algebraic closure of a finite extension $E$ of $F$. WLOG we can suppose $E/F$ Galois and so $J$ normal in $I_F$ and so in $W_F$. Since it is normal in $W_F$, then it is in the kernel of the representation. Now, let $\phi$ be a Frobenius element in $W_F$. It acts by conjugation on the finite group $I_F/J$, so some power of $\phi^d$ acts trivially. Thus $\rho(\phi^d)$ commutes with $\rho(W_F)$ and so, by Schur, $\rho(\phi^d)$ must be scalar. Hence, the vectorial space generated by $\rho(x)$ is finite dimensional and so is $V$.

My doubts are

Why being normal in $W_F$ implies being in the kernel?
I am not totally sure about what we are doing with the Frobenius element to say that $\rho(\phi^d)$ acts trivially and hence we can use Schur.
The conclusion: how is it enough?



The statement we are using is: Let $H$ be a subgroup of a group $G$ acting on a representation $V$. Assume $V$ is irreducible, $H$ fixes a nonzero vector $v\in V$, and $H$ is normal. Then $H$ lies in the kernel of $V$.

Proof: Since $H$ is normal, the set of vectors fixed by $H$ is a subrepresentation. By assumption this is nonzero and hence since $V$ is irreducible it is all of $V$.

Since the action of $\phi^d$ by conjugation on $I_F/J$ is zero and $\rho: I_F \to \operatorname{Aut}(V)$  factors through $I_F/J$, the action of $\rho(\phi^d)$ by conjugation on $\rho(I_F)$ is zero, i.e $\rho(\phi^d)$ commutes with $\rho(I_F)$. Since $\rho(\phi^d)$ commutes with $\rho(\phi)$, and $\phi$ and $I_F$ generate $W_F$ so that $\rho(\phi)$ and $\rho(I_F)$ generate $\rho(W_F)$, $\rho(\phi^d)$ commutes with $\rho(W_F)$.

The statement we are using is: Let $H$ be a finite-index subgroup of a group $G$ acting on a representation $V$. Assume $V$ is irreducible, $H$ has finite index, and every element of $H$ acts as scalars. Then $V$ is finite-dimensional.


Proof: Take any nonzero $v\in V$. Fix coset representatives $r_i$ for the cosets of $G/H$. Then for $g\in G$, $gv$ is a scalar multiple of $r_i v$ for some $i$. Hence the $r_i v$ span $G v$, but $Gv$ generates a nontrivial $G$-invariant subspace of $V$ and thus $G v$ generates $V$, so the $r_i v $ span $G v$.

Thank you very much, I have only another one doubt. I understood the proposition that you are using in order to conclude, but it isn't clear to me who is the subgroup of $W_F$ of finite index you are referring to. We know that $\phi^d$ acts as a scalar, so all its power act as a scalar, but what after that?

@Mario $\langle \phi^d, J \rangle$.
